# Meaning of trackbar

Tags: programming-languages, opencv

the function cvCreateTrackbar create the trackbar(slider) 
with the specified name and range,,,
my question, what is the **trackbar**??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trackbar is a slider GUI component:

|--------------------[]---------|

You can use it to adjust some values in a specified range.

Answer (score 0):

Try making one yourself. This might help: http://aishack.in/tutorials/highgui-creating-interfaces/